# Как получить число m из n?

Tags: c++

Есть числа n, m
За одну операцию вы можете:

- Уменьшить n на 1. После этой операций n должен оставаться положительным.
- Увеличить n в два раза.

Какое минимальное количество операций придется совершить?

Пример:

- Входные данные:
  4 6
- Выходные данные:
  2

Comment: Поиск в ширину?

Comment: да,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

Comment: Ну так если вы знаете, как, то что ж вы спрашиваете? Или вы хотите, чтоб тут выстроилась очередь желающих сделать вашу домашку? Нет, с этим вам куда-то [сюда](http://bit.ly/37fS3gS).

Comment: Полагаю, кроме поиска в ширину есть решение использующее алгебру. Оно может оказаться эффективнее и красивее.

Comment: Так и есть: помимо поиска в ширину `O(n+m)` с длинной арифметикой, есть решение за `O(log(n + m))` без длинной арифметики. Поспешили закрыть вопрос, поспешили.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Давайте голосовать за переоткрытие :) Я свой голос отдал.

Answer (score 1):

подсказка:

1. оценить, что меньше - при ситуации `m1/n1 = 2^r` `r` или `m-n`
2. определить, что лучше - достичь `m1` и `n1` из `m` и `n` через вычитания или через  )